# What is the "openssh-blacklist" package? Is it related to the Debian OpenSSL bug?

Tags: tls, ssh

What is the "openssh-blacklist" package? Is it related to the Debians OpenSSL bug?

Comment: FYI, subject package dropped as of Debian Stretch (see [here](https://linux.debian.user.narkive.com/oKNwAc24/openssh-packages-no-longer-suggest-openssh-blacklist)).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes it is related to the Debian OpenSSL "bug". It contains a list of of all DSA-1024 and RSA-2048 keys generated by a Debian sabotaged OpenSSL PRNG.

Answer (score 4):

Using the ssh-vulnkey you can check private key against this database. E.g. to check your (ssh) private key use

```
 $ ssh-vulnkey -v .ssh/id_rsa
```

For the server key

```
 # ssh-vulnkey -v /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
```