# Consequences of .ssh/authorized_keys being world-readable

Tags: ssh, openssh, obscurity

OpenSSH sshd enforces mode `0600` for `authorized_keys` when `StrictMode` is enabled. How is mode `0644` more vulnerable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`sshd_config` man page](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config) says

> **StrictModes**
> Specifies  whether  sshd(8)  should  check  file modes and ownership of the user's files and home directory before accepting login.  This is normally  desirable  because  novices  sometimes  accidentally  leave  their  directory  or  files world-writable.  The default is yes.  Note that this does not apply to  ChrootDirectory, whose permissions and ownership are checked unconditionally.

I believe this refers not to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` but rather to `~/.ssh` itself, which typically contains your private keys. With `~/.ssh` set to mode `0700` (`drwx------`), *nothing* inside it can be accessed by other users (except root). This happens to mean `authorized_keys` itself cannot be world-readable (unless you use the `AuthorizedKeysFile` config item to specify another location).

The risks to a publicly-visible `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file are pretty minimal but do exist: if you have compromised keys (the attacker has access to them) or keys that are weak (e.g. low bit size or old cryptosystem), an attacker might be able to replicate or use those keys and this file might tell them which system(s) to try them on.

Consider [CVE-2008-0166](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2008-0166), a bug in Debian's OpenSSL build's random number generator. Debian had to create the [openssh-blacklist](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/3422/42391) package as a short-term solution to ensure the weak keys could be weeded out.

Answer (score 2):

One of the principles of information security is to restrict permissions and privileges as much as possible.  Under this principle, only the minimum necessary permissions and privileges are granted to users, files, processes, etc.  `StrictMode` applies this principle.

The reason for this principle is to reduce the chances of giving an attacker something that could be useful to him/her.  In this case, an attacker that has read access to `authorized_keys` would be able see other hosts are able to connect to this host.  Knowing this information, the attacker could then look for ways to breach one of these other hosts, in order to gain access to this host.  The philosophy here is - why give the attacker something that he/she may be able to use, when there is nothing to be gained by doing so?